# Как реализовать работу с коллекцией для алгоритма поиска

Tags: c#, исключения, коллекции

У меня есть List в котором хранятся все клетки на игровом поле, у каждой клетки есть два состояния - проходима или нет (стена). Так как для генерации поля используется клеточный автомат, то некоторые "комнаты" оказываются изолированными. Собственно, попробовал написать алгоритм, который бы проходил по коллекции и создавал комнаты из клеток, но, судя по всему компилятор ругается на то, что нельзя изменять коллекцию (очередь) в момент работы с ней.
Вот код тех моментов, которые вызывают ошибку.
[image: Код ошибки]

```
public List<Room> rooms;
public List<GameObject> cells;

public void CreateRooms ()
{
    int numberOfRooms = 0;
    foreach (GameObject cell in cells)
    {

        if (cell.GetComponent<Cell>().isWall == false && cell.GetComponent<Cell>().state == "free")
        {
            rooms[numberOfRooms] = GenerateRoom(cell);
            numberOfRooms++;
        }
    }
}

public Room GenerateRoom (GameObject startCell)
{
    int cellInRoom = 0;
    List<GameObject> newRoom = new List<GameObject>();
    Room room = new Room();
    Queue<GameObject> stack = new Queue<GameObject>();
    stack.Enqueue(startCell);
    do
    {
        GameObject temp = stack.Dequeue();
        List<GameObject> TempList = new List<GameObject>();
        TempList = temp.GetComponent<Cell>().idleNeighbors;
        for (int i = 0; i < TempList.Count; i++ )
        {
            newRoom[cellInRoom] = TempList[i];
            cellInRoom++;
            stack.Enqueue(TempList[i]);
        }
    } while (stack.Count != 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < newRoom.Count; i++)
    {
        room.room.Add(newRoom[i]);
    }
    return room;
}
```

Comment: На какой строке выдаёт исключение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` возникает не при изменении очереди, а когда индекс элемента, к которому вы обращаетесь, выходит за границы очереди. В вашем случае это, видимо, происходит в строке

```
newRoom[cellInRoom] = TempList[i];
```

т.к. список `newRoom` определен без заданного количества элементов

```
List<GameObject> newRoom = new List<GameObject>();
```

Соответственно, в нем нет элементов, и при обращении к первому элементу возникает исключение.

Используйте метод `Add()` класса `List`

```
newRoom.Add(TempList[i]);
```

P.S. Не называйте экземпляр класса `Queue` именем `stack`, строчка `stack.Enqueue(TempList[i]);` режет глаз, все-таки стэк и очередь разные понятия

Comment: Большое спасибо, ответ помог.